# undirected weighted graph to xml

Tags: xml, graph, weighted

I want to represent an undirected graph, like this one :

http://cnx.org/content/m29399/latest/Picture%202.png

into an xml file. 
I'm not really sure how to begin.

EDIT: I want the data in xml format, so I can reconstruct the graph using the xml.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel, just use one of the already existing XML-based graph formats: [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/), [XGMML](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/research/groups/pb/punin/public_html/XGMML/) or [GXL](http://www.gupro.de/GXL/). GraphML seems to be the easiest to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to turn the graphic into xml, or do you have the data in some format already?

The first is hard, for the second you can take a look at [Boost::Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Comment: From boost graph you should be able to export to GraphML.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with c++, so I'm not sure how to use Boost::Graph. The application that will use the xml will be written in java.

Comment: Take a look at GraphML anyway, it might be a good format you can use.

Answer (score 0):

A graph consists of vertices and edges.  So at the top level the XML description should look like this

```
<graph>
    <vertices>...</vertices>
    <edges>...</edges>
</graph>
```

The `<vertices>` container will have `<vertex>` elements to carry the information for each vertex.  In particular, you will need a unique identifier by which edges can refer to a vertex.  So, something like this

```
    <vertices>
        <vertex id="A">other information, if needed</vertex>
        <vertex id="B">...</vertex>
        ...
    </vertices>
```

Each `<edge>` inside the `<edges>` container will need at least three pieces of information: the vertices connected, and the weight on the edge. Thus, for example

```
    <edges>
        <edge ends="A B">7</edge>
        <edge ends="B C">8</edge>
        ...
    </edges>
```

You can put all this into a schema where, for example, you can enforce a requirement that the 'ends' attribute carries references to ids of vertices that do exist in the graph (viz., look up xs:ID and xs:IDREF in the XML Schema documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I kept trying things and this seems to be working :

```
   <Nodes>
       <Node>
           <Name>A</Name>
       </Node> 
       <Node>
           <Name>B</Name>
       </Node> 
        ....
   </Nodes>

   <Routes>
       <Route>
          <from>A</from>
          <to>B</to>
          <cost>7</cost>
        </Route>
        ....
   </Routes>
```

Probably not the best way but this works for me :)`enter code here`